# Where are the beta badges?

Tags: bug, status-completed, beta, badges

On the Politics beta, [nobody has the beta badge](https://politics.stackexchange.com/badges/30/beta), although [16](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25906/politics) people fulfilled their commitment.

By comparison, other recent betas have beta badges: [58 at ExpressionEngine](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/badges/30/beta), [25 at Robots](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/badges/30/beta), [32 at Geneology & Family History](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/badges/30/beta), [29 at Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/badges/30/beta), etc.

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66220/172266), *The beta badge is for those that participated in the private beta week. It is awarded shortly after the public beta starts.*. According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81840/172266), *participated* means *earning at least three bronze badges* (ultimate source [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/172266)).

Why not at Politics SE?

Comment: AFAIK the "three bronze badges" requirement has changed, but I'm not so sure what's the current one. That said, beta badges will appear eventually, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, look - [31 Users earned this badge](https://politics.stackexchange.com/badges/30/beta).